# Need help printing out individual JSON data to command line

Tags: express

I am currently building a full-stack website using the MEAN stack. I have a problem with console logging the first title which is "Star Trek: The Motion Picture". I was able to Parse the JSON but I can't get the title first of the JSON file to appear on my command line. 
Here is the JSON file below

```
 {"data":[
 {
"title":"Star Trek: The Motion Picture",
"imageURL":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/df/Star_Trek_The_Motion_Picture_poster.png"
},
{
  "title":"Star Trek: The Wrath of Khan",
  "imageURL":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9a/Star_Trek_II_The_Wrath_of_Khan.png"
},
{
  "title":"Star Trek III:The Search For Spock",
  "imageURL":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/Star_Trek_III_The_Search_for_Spock.png"
},
{
  "title":"Star Trek IV:The Voyage Home",
    "imageURL":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/68/Star_Trek_IV_The_Voyage_Home.png"
},
{
  "title":"Star Trek V: The Final Frontier",
  "imageURL":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7c/Star_Trek_V_The_Final_Frontier.png"
},
{
  "title":"Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country",
      "imageURL":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fa/Star_Trek_VI-poster.png"
}

]}
```

Also here is my server file running with express js

```
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var body_parser=require('body-parser');
var fs= require('fs');
//var confog=require('./data.json');
var app=express();

app.set('use engine','ejs');



var headerText="";
var subText="";
var odj="";
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/starTrekData');

fs.readFile('data.json','utf8',function(err,data){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  console.log(data.title);
 });


app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(express.static('render'));





app.get('/',function(req,res){
  headerText="Star Trek Movies";
  res.render('render/index.ejs',{opening:headerText});
});
app.get('/home',function(req,res){
  headerText="Star Trek Movies";
  res.render('render/index.ejs',{opening:headerText});
});
//Tells about the creator of the website which is me...
app.get('/about',function(req,res){

 var name="About me";
 res.render('render/about.ejs',{title:name});
});
app.get("/contact",function(req,res){
  headerText="Contact Me";
  res.render("render/contact.ejs",{title:headerText});
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Its listening on 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the very first title in your file then you have to write it like that:
`console.log(JSON.parse(data).data[0].title);`

Maybe write it a little bit different for better reading like:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(data);
var title = myData.data[0].title;
console.log(title);
```

Explanation:

- `JSON.parse(data)` -> converts your String to a JSON object. See
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
- `data` -> because the element you search for is in this object
- `[0]` -> because data is an array and you want to access the first index
- `title` -> because it's the actual property you want to access as far as I understand.